# How do I extract the text before and after a known marker with a Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

Can anybody tell me how to identify the middle part `interestedInThis` and backreference the prefix: `fontsize=12` and postfix: `fontstyle=bold` as `${1}` and `${2}`?

I'm dealing with this string:

```
<fontsize=12 interestedInThis fontstyle=bold>
```

Addendum: Sorry, I was not precise enough, here are the specifics:

- prefix and postfix could be absent
- prefix and postfix can be any string, not necessarily fontsize, resp. fontstyle
- I know for sure, what I am looking for, namely `interestedInThis` and it will be separated through whitespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<([^>]*)interestedInThis([^>]*)>
```

Comment: Add a ? to the .* or else it will be greedy and match all the rest of the string: <(fontsize=\w+)\s+(.*?)\s+(fontstyle=\w+)>

Comment: Or, better, change the .* to \S* (or \S+ since I presume it shouldn't match zero characters).  While non-greedy * is useful, it's always better to specify what you actually want, and what you want here is non-whitespace characters (\S), not anything-but-newline characters (.).

Answer (score 0):

For your example, this could work

```
(<fontsize=\d+) (\w+) (fontstyle=bold>)
```

Unfortunatly, Perl doesn't seem to support named backreferences so I think you are stuck with `<fontsize=12 in $1, ImInterestedInThis in $2 & fontstyle=bold> in $3.`

regards,
Lieven

Comment: Dave, time to update my Regexbuddy then. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Basically

```
(<fontsize=12) (\S*) (fontstyle=bold>)
```

But, will the attribute values change? And, do you have to account for variable whitespace? If so, the above mutates into:

```
(<fontsize=\d+)\s+(\S*)\s+(fontstyle=.*>)
```

Also, in the above, by using \S, interestedInThis can contain anything that is not whitespace. If there is whitespace there too, for example interestedInThis is actually something like `class="x" id="y"`, then maybe:

```
(<fontsize=\d+)(.*)(fontstyle=.*>)
```

Note that $2 is interestedInThis, and $1/$3 is actually your end pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my $result = m/(.*)(InterestedInThis)(.*)/;
```

Now:

- `$result` is true if it found a match to the format.
- InterestedInThis is in `$2`, though you already know what it is.
- prefix (EVERYTHING before "InterestedInThis") is in `$1`.
- postfix (EVERYTHING after "InterestedInThis") is in `$3`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want;

```
<(.* )?InterestedInThis( .*)?>
```

It will return the the pre- and post-fix if they're there, but will still match if only one or neither are present.

It does have a minor problem that the spaces will be included in the tagged expressions, but that should be easy to remove after the match.

Alternatively, you could use lookahead / lookbehind to try to filter the spaces out as part of the match:

```
<(.*(?= ))? ?InterestedInThis ?((?<= ).*)?>
```